# Data from URL NSString as NSInteger Instead

Tags: swift

Im fairly new to swift. If I wanted to get data a number from a url this script works fine, but let's say I would like to add and subtract to that number I am unable to because its a string and not a number. How would I convert this to a NSInteger or a NSNumber?

```
   let myURLString = "https://canihazip.com/s"
    if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {
        do {
            let myHTMLString = try NSString(contentsOf: myURL as URL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            let myIpAddress = myHTMLString
            print("Your IP address is ")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Swift. Use `URL`, not `NSURL`. Use `String`, not `NSString`. And never load data from a remote URL like this. Use `URLSession`.

Comment: @rmaddy speaks truth. your code is doing a synchronous network call. The app will freeze until the network request is complete. If there is a hiccup in the connection to the remote host, the UI will stop responding until it either completes, errors out, or times out. Network requests can take 30, 60, even 120 seconds before they time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the contents of simple urls like that with `String`'s init(contentsOf:) method. then remove the `.` and cast to integer

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://canihazip.com/s") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
        let formattedContents = contents.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
        print(Int(formattedContents))
    } catch {
        // an error occured
    }
} else {
    // the URL was bad!
}
```

if you need each dotted address use `.map` and `.split(separator:)` to get a list of optional integer values to edit.

```
    let ip = "123.456.31.10"
    let badip = "123.456.fail.10"

    let dottedIpArray = ip.split(separator: ".").map { Int($0) }
    let corruptIpArray = badip.split(separator: ".").map { Int($0) }

    print(dottedIpArray) // [Optional(123), Optional(456), Optional(31), Optional(10)]
    print(corruptIpArray) // [Optional(123), Optional(456), nil, Optional(10)]
```

**Updated, with `URLSession`**

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: "https://canihazip.com/s")!
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Do something if an error occurs
            print("An Error Occurred: \(error)")
            return
        }
        // ensure we have data, response is OK, and data can be encoded to string
        if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
            if let stringdata = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                let dottedIpArray = stringdata.split(separator: ".").map { Int($0) }
                print(dottedIpArray) //[Optional(168), Optional(192), Optional(0), Optional(1)]
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

[URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) Documentation.

[Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/711/)

Comment: Except that doing synchronous network calls like this is a **very** bad idea, as rmaddy says in his comment.

Comment: Do not load data from a remote URL using this method. Use `URLSession`.

Comment: Although I understand why you should use `URLSession`... The reason I provided code similar to OP's code is because the original question `How would I convert this to a NSInteger or a NSNumber?` is an XY problem unrelated to the network call, I wrote the code in a way OP would be able to use it as is. Instead of a long detailed answer to the question using `URLSession`. instead of saying something like "this is bad" or "don't do that" perhaps some resource's as you why is a better idea...

Comment: Alright so using URLSession I've rewritten the code to reflect the following, how would I return the value as an integer vs encoding it as a string?                           `let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://canihazip.com/s")!
let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) -> Void in
    if let data = data {
        let string2 = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(string2) //JSONSerialization
        
    }
}
task.resume()`

Comment: @fcs132 answer is updated to include a simple `URLSession` example.